# Ошибка компиляции после смены Compile sdk version в android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk

Здравствуйте. Я работяю с Android Studio. При создании модуля в проекте, IDE автоматически выставляет Compile sdk version=23. Но мне нужна версия 21.
Я изменил в свойствах модуля версию [image: скриншот], но у меня остаются темы 23-й версии, и, соответственно, выбивает ошибку:

```
C:\Users\hasana\AndroidStudioProjects\Androidlessons\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values-v23\values-v23.xml
Error:(3) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.
```

[image: скриншот].

Comment: а вы библиотеки не используете 23 версии, например `appcompat` ?

Comment: @pavel Точно, я её удалил из Gradle-а, но теперь осталась проблема с темами? потому что используется "Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar". Не подскажите, как в студии отключить использование appcompat библиотеки?

Comment: лучше не отключайте, просто измените цифры `23` в названии на `21`. Но не удаляйте из `gradle`

Comment: а можно полюбопытствовать зачем вам compileSdkVersion именно 21? чем 23 не устраивает?

Comment: @xkor метод, который я испльзую был изъят в 23-й версии.

Comment: @GiorgiGusakov это чтож за метод такой? Не припоминаю что бы что то убирали не дав замену.

Comment: @xkor Notification.setLatestEventInfo(); замена скорее всего есть, но тут  ещё хотелось узнать, как менять к версии в студии.

Answer (score 2):

Вы немного все путаете, оставьте `compileSdkVersion` как есть, т.е. `23`, а настройте `targetSdkVersion` как вам надо:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        ...
        targetSdkVersion 21
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: В самом деле. Спасибо.